# Building an image with different users set inside the container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My `Dockerfile` has the following command

```
USER someuser
```

Sometimes I have to debug my image or do some investigations so I have to be logged in as `root` user inside the container. Right now I have to put `#` before `USER` command and rebuild the image.

Can I put some arguments or set a `root` user in a `docker run` command to get rid of rebuilding the image for debug purposes?
And what is the best way to organize that kind of creating Dockerfiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
docker run -it --rm --user root <your_image> <cmd>
```

or if you are using `ENTRYPOINT`

```
docker run -it --rm --user root --entrypoint <cmd> <your_image>
```

Comment: your way is correct, create a user (or use predefined one), assign perms to an app, change the owner of PID1 to that user, debug with user root option.

Comment: I didn't know such an option.  Thank you very much!